# How to build a drag scenario using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a mechanic similar to this link https://demos.littleworkshop.fr/demos/infinitown/. Ignoring Three.JS's 3D features, I wish my user could drag the scene, this being an img tag or even a div with 3D transform, but the drag movement is just as smooth. How could I build this?

My first attempt https://codepen.io/diogenesjup-the-encoder/pen/xxdEoEg almost worked, however, the 3D transform, left the parent DIV and the drag movement is not so fluid.

```css
#square {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
  transform: rotateX( -70deg) rotateY( 14deg) rotateZ( 38deg) translateX(16px) translateY(-19px) translateZ(20px) scale(1) skewX( -19deg) skewY( 1deg);
  overflow: auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: rgb(249 249 251) 1px 1px 0px 1px, rgb(34 33 81 / 1%) -1px 0px 28px 0px, rgb(34 33 81 / 25%) 28px 28px 28px 0px;
}

#map {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  transform: rotateX( -70deg) rotateY( 14deg) rotateZ( 38deg) translateX(16px) translateY(-19px) translateZ(20px) scale(1) skewX( -19deg) skewY( 1deg);
  overflow: auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: rgb(249 249 251) 1px 1px 0px 1px, rgb(34 33 81 / 1%) -1px 0px 28px 0px, rgb(34 33 81 / 25%) 28px 28px 28px 0px;
}
```

Comment: I think you should go with jquery UI's drag functionality.

Comment: @seriously So if you look at what I put in my example link, I used JQuery's drag, but the mechanics were very different.

Comment: ok so to get this clear your first question is your inner div is not accurately contained in the parent div. And your second question is the drag movement is not fluid by fluid do you mean smooth?

Comment: @Spectric noted

Comment: The two things are perhaps linked. The 3D transform visually makes the div stay outside the parent div (however hierarchically one is inside the other). And the drag movement isn't smooth (because the Jquery UI I used doesn't have this feature).

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in the question itself, not only in an external site. I've created a snippet for you, please add the rest of the code to the additional boxes in the snippet interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inner div being out of bound issues add margin in the direction of the out of bounding in your case try adding `margin-right: 35%` for the `#map` div. For the smoothing behavior modify the ui.position property inside the drag callback. Keep on adjusting the added value to get the needed smoothing. (I subtracted 7 in both just as an example).

```
$("#map").draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    ui.position.left = ui.position.left-7;
    ui.position.top = ui.position.top-7;
  }
});
```